# TcpClient - how to send messages and receive responses?

Tags: reactor-netty

I want to do something like below:

```
TcpClient client = init();
String response1 = sendMsg(TcpClient client, String msg1);
String response2 = sendMsg(TcpClient client, String msg2);
close(TcpClient client);
```

appreciate any responses.

My unit test is below:

```
@Test
public void tcpServerHandlesTlvOverSsl() throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

    SelfSignedCertificate cert = new SelfSignedCertificate();
    SslContextBuilder serverOptions = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert.certificate(), cert.privateKey());
    SslContext clientOptions = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build();
    final TcpServer server =
            TcpServer.create()
                    .host("localhost")
                    .secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(serverOptions));

    // this is an relay tcp server
    DisposableServer connectedServer =
            server
                    .doOnConnection(connection -> {
                        // tlv is our customized protocol
                        connection.addHandlerLast("tlvEncoder", new TlvEncoder());
                        connection.addHandlerLast("tlvDecoder", new TlvDecoder());

                        // something like creating a new tcp client to the target server should be done here
                    })
                    .handle((in, out) ->
                            out.sendObject(
                                    in
                                            .receiveObject()
                                            .log("[Server received]")
                                            .ofType(TlvMessage.class)
                                            .flatMap(tlv -> {
                                                // do some work on each received message
                                                fixTlv(tlv);
                                                log.debug("Server fixed the tlv message: {}", tlv.toString());
                                                return Mono.just(tlv);
                                            })
                                            .doOnNext(tlv -> {
                                                if (isLegalType(tlv.getType())) {
                                                    latch.countDown();
                                                }
                                                // then forward the fixed tlv message to the target server by using the new created tcp client
                                                log.debug("Server forwards to the target server: {}", tlv.toString());

                                                // do something else with the response from the target server

                                                if (TYPE_UPSTREAM_FINISH == tlv.getType()) {
                                                    // the closing flag is accounted
                                                    log.debug("Server closing client to the target server.");
                                                    // closing the new created tcp client to the target server
                                                }
                                            })
                            )
                    )
                    .wiretap(true)
                    .bindNow();

    assertNotNull(connectedServer);

    // simulating a client to the relay server
    final TcpClient client = TcpClient.create()
            .host("localhost")
            .port(connectedServer.address().getPort())
            .secure(spec -> spec.sslContext(clientOptions));

    Connection connectedClient = client
            .doOnConnected(connection -> {
                connection.addHandlerLast("tlvEncoder", new TlvEncoder());
                connection.addHandlerLast("tlvDecoder", new TlvDecoder());
            })
            .doOnDisconnected(connection -> log.info("Client disconnected"))
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .handle((in, out) -> {
                        in
                                .receiveObject()
                                .log("[Client received]")
                                .ofType(TlvMessage.class)
                                .doOnNext(tlv -> {
                                    // do some work on each response from the relay server
                                    if (isLegalType(tlv.getType())) {
                                        latch.countDown();
                                    }
                                });

                        return out
                                // simulating requests to the relay server
                                .sendObject(Flux.just(
                                        demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_INIT, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3F1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1001\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\",\"sn\":\"91598059-4d06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7\"}"),
                                        demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_FINISH, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3A1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1002\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\"}")
                                        )
                                )
                                .neverComplete();
                    }
            )
            .wiretap(true)
            .connectNow();

    assertNotNull(connectedClient);

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    log.info("Client sends object after 3 seconds.");
    connectedClient.outbound().sendObject(
            Flux.just(
                    demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_INIT, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3B1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1003\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\",\"sn\":\"91598059-dd06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7\"}"),
                    demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_FINISH, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3C1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1004\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\"}")
            )
    );

    assertTrue("Latch was counted down", latch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    connectedClient.disposeNow();
    connectedServer.disposeNow();
}
```

The `demo` method is used to assemble a tlv(our customized protocol) object.

The key logs are the below:

```
17:16:21.104 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187] REGISTERED
17:16:21.105 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187] CONNECT: localhost/127.0.0.1:60092
17:16:21.117 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] SSL enabled using engine SSLEngineImpl
17:16:21.118 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.sslHandler = io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler), (reactor.left.loggingHandler = io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler), (reactor.left.sslReader = reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$SslReadHandler), (BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
17:16:21.121 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] REGISTERED
17:16:21.121 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] ACTIVE
17:16:21.170 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
17:16:21.170 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
17:16:21.170 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
17:16:21.170 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
17:16:21.186 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] ACTIVE
17:16:21.186 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] Registering pool release on close event for channel
17:16:21.188 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] Channel connected, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
17:16:21.202 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] READ COMPLETE
17:16:21.203 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.util.InsecureTrustManagerFactory - Accepting a server certificate: CN=example.com
17:16:21.241 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] READ COMPLETE
17:16:21.247 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
17:16:21.248 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
17:16:21.350 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] Added decoder [tlvEncoder] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.loggingHandler, tlvEncoder, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
17:16:21.351 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] Added decoder [tlvDecoder] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.loggingHandler, tlvEncoder, tlvDecoder, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
17:16:21.351 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] Handler is being applied: com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests$$Lambda$7/824208363@3252dfd9
17:16:21.367 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] Writing object 
17:16:21.375 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
17:16:21.377 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] INFO [Server received] - onSubscribe(FluxReceive)
17:16:21.379 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] INFO [Server received] - request(256)
17:16:21.380 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] READ COMPLETE
17:16:21.381 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] HANDSHAKEN: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
17:16:21.381 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] USER_EVENT: SslHandshakeCompletionEvent(SUCCESS)
17:16:21.381 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] onStateChange(PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092]}, [connected])
17:16:21.381 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.resources.PooledConnectionProvider - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] onStateChange(ChannelOperations{PooledConnection{channel=[id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092]}}, [configured])
17:16:21.381 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] Added decoder [tlvEncoder] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.loggingHandler, tlvEncoder, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
17:16:21.382 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] Added decoder [tlvDecoder] at the end of the user pipeline, full pipeline: [reactor.left.sslHandler, reactor.left.loggingHandler, tlvEncoder, tlvDecoder, reactor.right.reactiveBridge, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
17:16:21.382 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] Handler is being applied: com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests$$Lambda$27/1754662105@7f8c9193
17:16:21.652 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] Writing object 
17:16:21.662 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] WRITE: 143B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 00 89 00 00 00 7b 22 70 61 72 61 6d 22 3a 22 |......{"param":"|
|00000010| 7b 5c 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 69 64 5c 22 3a 5c |{\"device-id\":\|
|00000020| 22 33 46 31 38 30 36 31 31 38 38 30 30 43 36 37 |"3F1806118800C67|
|00000030| 38 5c 22 7d 22 2c 22 70 69 64 22 3a 22 2d 31 30 |8\"}","pid":"-10|
|00000040| 30 31 22 2c 22 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 70 22 3a 22 |01","clientip":"|
|00000050| 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 22 |xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"|
|00000060| 2c 22 73 6e 22 3a 22 39 31 35 39 38 30 35 39 2d |,"sn":"91598059-|
|00000070| 34 64 30 36 2d 34 34 37 61 2d 38 37 38 66 2d 35 |4d06-447a-878f-5|
|00000080| 35 31 36 33 37 62 63 61 66 38 39 5f 37 22 7d    |51637bcaf89_7"} |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
17:16:21.664 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] WRITE: 97B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 04 00 5b 00 00 00 7b 22 70 61 72 61 6d 22 3a 22 |..[...{"param":"|
|00000010| 7b 5c 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 69 64 5c 22 3a 5c |{\"device-id\":\|
|00000020| 22 33 41 31 38 30 36 31 31 38 38 30 30 43 36 37 |"3A1806118800C67|
|00000030| 38 5c 22 7d 22 2c 22 70 69 64 22 3a 22 2d 31 30 |8\"}","pid":"-10|
|00000040| 30 32 22 2c 22 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 70 22 3a 22 |02","clientip":"|
|00000050| 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 22 |xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"|
|00000060| 7d                                              |}               |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
17:16:21.664 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] FLUSH
17:16:21.666 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] READ: 240B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 00 89 00 00 00 7b 22 70 61 72 61 6d 22 3a 22 |......{"param":"|
|00000010| 7b 5c 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 69 64 5c 22 3a 5c |{\"device-id\":\|
|00000020| 22 33 46 31 38 30 36 31 31 38 38 30 30 43 36 37 |"3F1806118800C67|
|00000030| 38 5c 22 7d 22 2c 22 70 69 64 22 3a 22 2d 31 30 |8\"}","pid":"-10|
|00000040| 30 31 22 2c 22 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 70 22 3a 22 |01","clientip":"|
|00000050| 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 22 |xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"|
|00000060| 2c 22 73 6e 22 3a 22 39 31 35 39 38 30 35 39 2d |,"sn":"91598059-|
|00000070| 34 64 30 36 2d 34 34 37 61 2d 38 37 38 66 2d 35 |4d06-447a-878f-5|
|00000080| 35 31 36 33 37 62 63 61 66 38 39 5f 37 22 7d 04 |51637bcaf89_7"}.|
|00000090| 00 5b 00 00 00 7b 22 70 61 72 61 6d 22 3a 22 7b |.[...{"param":"{|
|000000a0| 5c 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 69 64 5c 22 3a 5c 22 |\"device-id\":\"|
|000000b0| 33 41 31 38 30 36 31 31 38 38 30 30 43 36 37 38 |3A1806118800C678|
|000000c0| 5c 22 7d 22 2c 22 70 69 64 22 3a 22 2d 31 30 30 |\"}","pid":"-100|
|000000d0| 32 22 2c 22 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 70 22 3a 22 78 |2","clientip":"x|
|000000e0| 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 22 7d |xx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}|
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
17:16:21.667 [reactor-tcp-nio-1] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpClient - [id: 0x019c3187, L:/127.0.0.1:60093 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:60092] READ COMPLETE
17:16:21.667 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.handler.TlvDecoder - TlvDecoder read type: 1
17:16:21.667 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.handler.TlvDecoder - TlvDecoder read length: 137
17:16:21.668 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.handler.TlvDecoder - TlvDecoder read data success: {"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3F1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1001","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","sn":"91598059-4d06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7"}
17:16:21.668 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.handler.TlvDecoder - TlvDecoder read type: 4
17:16:21.668 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.handler.TlvDecoder - TlvDecoder read length: 91
17:16:21.668 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.handler.TlvDecoder - TlvDecoder read data success: {"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3A1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1002","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}
17:16:21.669 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] INFO [Server received] - onNext(TlvMessage(type=1, length=137, value={"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3F1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1001","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","sn":"91598059-4d06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7"}))
17:16:21.670 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests - Server fixed the tlv message: TlvMessage(type=1, length=157, value={"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3F1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1001","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","sn":"91598059-4d06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7","fixed":"by server"})
17:16:21.671 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests - Server forwards to the target server: TlvMessage(type=1, length=157, value={"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3F1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1001","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","sn":"91598059-4d06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7","fixed":"by server"})
17:16:21.671 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] WRITE: 163B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 01 00 9d 00 00 00 7b 22 70 61 72 61 6d 22 3a 22 |......{"param":"|
|00000010| 7b 5c 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 69 64 5c 22 3a 5c |{\"device-id\":\|
|00000020| 22 33 46 31 38 30 36 31 31 38 38 30 30 43 36 37 |"3F1806118800C67|
|00000030| 38 5c 22 7d 22 2c 22 70 69 64 22 3a 22 2d 31 30 |8\"}","pid":"-10|
|00000040| 30 31 22 2c 22 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 70 22 3a 22 |01","clientip":"|
|00000050| 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 22 |xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"|
|00000060| 2c 22 73 6e 22 3a 22 39 31 35 39 38 30 35 39 2d |,"sn":"91598059-|
|00000070| 34 64 30 36 2d 34 34 37 61 2d 38 37 38 66 2d 35 |4d06-447a-878f-5|
|00000080| 35 31 36 33 37 62 63 61 66 38 39 5f 37 22 2c 22 |51637bcaf89_7","|
|00000090| 66 69 78 65 64 22 3a 22 62 79 20 73 65 72 76 65 |fixed":"by serve|
|000000a0| 72 22 7d                                        |r"}             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
17:16:21.671 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] INFO [Server received] - onNext(TlvMessage(type=4, length=91, value={"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3A1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1002","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}))
17:16:21.671 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests - Server fixed the tlv message: TlvMessage(type=4, length=111, value={"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3A1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1002","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","fixed":"by server"})
17:16:21.671 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests - Server forwards to the target server: TlvMessage(type=4, length=111, value={"param":"{\"device-id\":\"3A1806118800C678\"}","pid":"-1002","clientip":"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","fixed":"by server"})
17:16:21.671 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests - Server closing client to the target server.
17:16:21.672 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] WRITE: 117B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 04 00 6f 00 00 00 7b 22 70 61 72 61 6d 22 3a 22 |..o...{"param":"|
|00000010| 7b 5c 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 2d 69 64 5c 22 3a 5c |{\"device-id\":\|
|00000020| 22 33 41 31 38 30 36 31 31 38 38 30 30 43 36 37 |"3A1806118800C67|
|00000030| 38 5c 22 7d 22 2c 22 70 69 64 22 3a 22 2d 31 30 |8\"}","pid":"-10|
|00000040| 30 32 22 2c 22 63 6c 69 65 6e 74 69 70 22 3a 22 |02","clientip":"|
|00000050| 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 2e 78 78 78 22 |xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"|
|00000060| 2c 22 66 69 78 65 64 22 3a 22 62 79 20 73 65 72 |,"fixed":"by ser|
|00000070| 76 65 72 22 7d                                  |ver"}           |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
17:16:21.672 [reactor-tcp-nio-2] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer - [id: 0x424c0204, L:/127.0.0.1:60092 - R:/127.0.0.1:60093] READ COMPLETE
17:16:24.384 [main] INFO com.baidu.iot.devicecloud.devicemanager.TcpServerTests - Client sends object after 3 seconds.

java.lang.AssertionError: Latch was counted down


Process finished with exit code -1
```

The created TcpClient doesn't work well, and I don't know how to correct, could someone point me a way to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues that I can see in your code:

1. In the TcpClient's `handle` method, you declare what you want to do with the incoming data, but you do not `subscribe` => nothing will be executed. So change the code to:

```java
        .handle((in, out) -> {
                    in
                            .receiveObject()
                            .log("[Client received]")
                            .ofType(TlvMessage.class)
                            .doOnNext(tlv -> {
                                // do some work on each response from the relay server
                                if (isLegalType(tlv.getType())) {
                                    latch.countDown();
                                }
                            })
                            .subscribe();

                    return out
                            // simulating requests to the relay server
                            .sendObject(Flux.just(
                                    demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_INIT, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3F1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1001\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\",\"sn\":\"91598059-4d06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7\"}"),
                                    demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_FINISH, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3A1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1002\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\"}")
                                    )
                            )
                            .neverComplete();
                }
        )
```

2. When you try to send the second message to the server, you again declare what you want to send but you do not `subscribe` => again nothing will be executed. Change the code to:

```java
    connectedClient.outbound().sendObject(
            Flux.just(
                    demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_INIT, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3B1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1003\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\",\"sn\":\"91598059-dd06-447a-878f-551637bcaf89_7\"}"),
                    demo(TYPE_UPSTREAM_FINISH, "{\"param\":\"{\\\"device-id\\\":\\\"3C1806118800C678\\\"}\",\"pid\":\"-1004\",\"clientip\":\"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\"}")
            )
    )
    .then()
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this valuable response. I've correct my code as exactly as you said, it works! The client wrote 4 messages in total and the server responded 4 of them. But why the client didn't receive any response from the server? I didn't see any log output by the client.

Comment: publish some logs as I'm not able to run your code or try to simplify the code so that it can be run by everyone.

Comment: Hi @Violeta Georgieva, I appreciate your patience, thank you very much. But there are too many logs to publish on this issue anymore. Anyway, in view of that learning curve is somehow steep to me, so this reactor-netty echo test has stopped for a period because I've implemented a proxy server by using netty, that's what I finally want. However, I will back to this reactor-netty echo test after I finished my work on netty, that's an emergency work assigned to me. I will expect and appreciate your necessary help when I back to reactor-netty for some difficult problem. Thanks again.